# Error Loger and verification authentification java

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to get my code to check if my username and password are in the database only I have errors everywhere. Do you have a solution?

here my code in my Login_form :

```
 PreparedStatement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    // donnez l'username et le password 
    String username = jTextField_Username.getText();
    String password = String.valueOf(jPasswordField.getPassword());

    // requete indiquant si les identifiants existent 
    String query = "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = ? AND 'password' = ?";

    try {
        st = Connecter.getConnection().prepareStatement(query)

        st.setString(1, username);
        st.setString(2, password);
        rs = st.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next())

        {
            // Show my new form 
        }else{
            // Error message 
        }


    } catch (SQLExeption ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Login_Form.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

and this is my code of my connector

```
package javaapplicationhotel2;
```

import java.sql.*;

public class Connecter {

```
static Object getConnection() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
Connection con; 



public Connecter() {
  try{
  Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
  }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
      System.err.println(e);


}
try{
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotel","root","");
}catch(SQLException e){System.err.println(e);}
}
Connection obtenirconnexion(){return con;}

PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String select__from_classe) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.



}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem seems to reside in your Connecter class. Especially in the `getConnection()` and `prepareStatement()` methods since they always return throwing an `UnsupportedException`. Another issue is that `getConnection()` is of the return type `Object`, even though you treat it as a Connector in your try block. Therefore I'd suggest you changing `getConnection`'s return type to Connection and returning a `new Connection()` or using `new Connection()` in the first place. Also you may want to replace your `setString(int, String)` calls, which presumably replace the '?' with the corresponding username and password, with `String.format(String, Object...)`. You can use this method to replace certain parts of a String (eg. %s for Strings, %d for Integer, etc.) So in your case you would use it as the following:

```
String format = "SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'username' = %s AND 'password' = %s;"
String query = String.format(format, username, password);
```

As a side note:
In modern jdbc you are actually not required to load the Driver class with `Class.forName(String)`, so you may omit it.

One last thing:
It'd be nice if you could indent your code appropriately the next time, since that would make understanding it a lot easier.